# iPhone: Reload view after switch back from foreground/background?

Tags: iphone, background, ios4

This is for iOS4 with multitask issue. How do I reload view after my app is re-appear from background running app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your view controller to listen for [`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification):

> Posted shortly before an application
>   leaves the background state on its way
>   to becoming the active application.

Also mentioned in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW3):

> The
>   `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`
>   notification is also available for
>   tracking when your application
>   reenters the foreground. Objects in
>   your application can use the default
>   notification center to register for
>   this notification.

In your handler for this notification, you can trigger whatever refreshing/redrawing you need.

You can read more about Notifications in the [Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW7) document.